# MySQL - 2 sums and 2 WHERE statements from one table into 2 columns

Tags: mysql

maybe this is an easy answer for someone but I searched and searched and failed.
Here's what I have: 1 Table that contains the following:

```
id, int
year, int
month, int
day, int
revenue, float
sub_category, text
```

What I'm trying to get is 1 SQL statement that returns 1 table with 3 columns to hold the sum of the revenue per month and sub_category

```
-------------------------------
| Month | revcomp1 | revcomp2 |
-------------------------------
|   01  | sumcat1  | sumcat2  |
-------------------------------
|   02  | sumcat1  | sumcat2  |
-------------------------------
|   ..  |    ..    |    ..    |
```

Here's the SQL Statement I was running:

```
SELECT 
 month,
 cast(sum(rev *-1) as decimal(10,2)) as REVCOMP1,
 0 as REVCOMP2
FROM 
 tbl_data
WHERE
 year='2014' and sub_category='comp1'
GROUP BY month, sub_category DESC

UNION

SELECT 
 month,
 0 as REVCOMP1
 cast(sum(rev *-1) as decimal(10,2)) as REVCOMP2,
FROM 
 tbl_data
WHERE
 year='2014' and sub_category='comp2'
GROUP BY month, sub_category DESC
```

But this doesn't really return the sums of a given month in one line...

Any help is really appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select month,
       cast(sum(case when sub_cateogry = 'comp1' then rev *-1 end) as decimal(10,2)) as REVCOMP1,
       cast(sum(case when sub_category = 'comp2' then rev *-1 end) as decimal(10,2)) as REVCOMP2
from tbl_data t
where year = '2014'
group by month;
```

Comment: Ok, but this gives me the very same sums in both revcomp1 and revcomp2 and is not filtered towards the company revenue...

Comment: @Borinho . . . It needed the conditional part.  Oops.